# A Spring test requires several beans that no being used by the controller

Tags: spring, junit, spring-webflux, spring-test

I have a test about a Spring (v2.2.2.RELEASE) controller which is failing because require some beans that the controller not need. Why this beans are required?

**Controller**

```
@Api(description = "Exercises")
@CrossOrigin(origins = ["*"])
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/exercises")
class ExerciseController(
        val repo: ExerciseRepository,
        val userAuditing: UserAuditing
) : ResourceRestController<Exercise, String>(repo)  {
    @PostMapping("")
    override fun create(@RequestBody resource: Exercise): Mono<ResponseEntity<Exercise>> {
        // TODO Free Coaches members just can create public exercises!
        return super.create(resource)
    }
}

abstract class ResourceRestController<T : Resource, ID>(private val repository: ReactiveMongoRepository<T, ID>) {
   @PostMapping
   open fun create(@RequestBody resource: T) = repository.save(resource)
            .map { o -> ResponseEntity(o, HttpStatus.CREATED) }
            .onErrorMap { err ->
                log.error("Error occurred while creating the resource", err);
                HttpServerErrorException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Error occurred while creating the resource")
   }
}
```

**Controller dependencies**

```kotlin
@Component
class UserAuditing : ReactiveBeforeConvertCallback<Resource> {

    val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserAuditing::class.java)

    override fun onBeforeConvert(entity: Resource, collection: String) = getCurrentUser()
            .flatMap{ user ->
                entity.lastModifiedBy = user
                entity.lastModifiedDate = Instant.now(Clock.systemUTC())

                if(entity.id == null) {
                    entity.createdBy = entity.lastModifiedBy
                    entity.createdDate = entity.lastModifiedDate
                }
                Mono.just(entity)
            }

    fun getCurrentUser() = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map { ctx -> ctx.authentication.principal }
            .cast(User::class.java)
            .map(User::getUsername)
}

interface ExerciseRepository : ReactiveMongoRepository<Exercise,String> {}
```

**Configuration**

```kotlin
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
class SecurityConfig(
        val tokenProvider: JwtTokenProvider,
        val customUserDetailsService: CustomUserDetailsService
) { 
}

@EnableWebFlux
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
class BackendApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<BackendApplication>(*args)
}
```

**Test**

```kotlin
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@WebFluxTest(ExerciseController::class)
@Import(UserAuditing::class)
class ExerciseControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var webClient: WebTestClient

    @MockBean
    lateinit var exerciseRepository: ExerciseRepository

    @Test
    fun create() {
        webClient.post()
                .uri("/")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .bodyValue("""
                    {
                      "ages": {
                        "start": 0,
                        "end": 0
                      },
                      "description": "Two queues of 5 players located in the bottom of the court. Every pla yer with a ball, ...",
                      "goals": [
                        "shoot"
                      ],
                      "id": "string",
                      "language": "es",
                      "length": 10,
                      "title": "Chickens, foxes and sneaks",
                      "visibility": "private"
                    }
                """.trimIndent())
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .is2xxSuccessful
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:118)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:412)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:825)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'trainingRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'reactiveMongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'reactiveMongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'reactiveMongoTemplate' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$281.000000007B795E90.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:860)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'reactiveMongoTemplate' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:805)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
    ... 69 more
```

Why I need mocking trainingRepository if it is not used in the ExerciseController?

Comment: `trainingRepository` is not the issue, `reactiveMongoTemplate` cannot be found.  You have got a `SpringRunner` annotation that is supposed to load the ApplicationContext, which trainingRepository and all dependencies it needs are a part of, no matter if you don't use it in your test.

Comment: @Matt no: it's a WebFluxTest, so it's only supposed to add the controller and the beans necessary for the controller layer (ObjectMapper, etc.). And the test is supposed to provide the mock dependencies. It's a slice test.

Comment: @Fran are you sure that UserAuditing doesn't have a dependency on TrainingRepository? Find all the beans where TrainingRepository is injected.

Comment: @JBNizet, oh I see. My bad.

Comment: @JBNizet Complety sure. I have just added it to the post. There is not any reference to TrainingRepository from UserAuditing or any other part related to the test.

Comment: Maybe you're using a configuration class which enables/configures (with code or with annotations) both the persistence slice and the controller slice. Make sure to use distinct configuration classes for all slices.

Comment: Mmh... I have just added my two configured classes with annotations (ConfigSecurity and BackendApplication). Maybe @SpringBootApplication ? Can you reference a sample about how to create a configuration class for a slice? Because I didn't find info in Google or Github, just I found how to exclude a configuration class for a test.

Comment: Your BackendApplication has both EnableWebFlux and EnableReactiveMongoRepositories. Create two separate configuration classes, each having only one of those annotations (i.e. one for each slice). And actually, only create one, because a Spring Boot application should never use EnableWebFlux, unless you don't want Boot to autoconfigure webflux, and instead want to configure everything by yourself. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-webflux-auto-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such as @JBNizet commented, I created two configuration classes and the annotations were moved.

This class replaces @EnableWebFlux in BackendApplication:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class WebfluxConfig : WebFluxConfigurer {
    override fun addResourceHandlers(registry: ResourceHandlerRegistry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui.html**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/")

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/")
    }
}
```

This class replaces @EnableReactiveMongoRepositories in BackendApplication:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
class MongoConfig {
}
```

So main class:

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
class BackendApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<BackendApplication>(*args)
}
```